# Laravel/Vue/Vuex is very slow with response

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js, laravel-translatable

I'm building a laravel/vue app. I also use vuex/vuetify however it's very slow when process any code and get response data. I have researched many days however I don't know why this happens. It's difficult to explain however I will try to show details:

I have:

PHP 7.3.5, XAMP on Windows 7 with 4GB Ram.

Laravel 5.8, Vuex, Vue Router, Vuetify, Laravel Translatable (Astrotomic).

When I run 1 seed with a loop of 10k records, it takes 4, 5 hours to process. If I use a simple PHP, it takes a few seconds...

Another, I just do a simple feature: upload csv with 400 records and insert it into database however the status will show canceled after 30s...The csv file is 205kb.
[image: process csv with file size 205kb]

I feel something is wrong. Maybe from Laravel 5.8 or Vuex or anything else. Not sure. Please advise.

Best Regards,

Chu

Comment: xdebug is enabled?

Comment: so disable it and restart apache

Comment: Hello Mohsen, I have checked my xampp and php.ini and I don't see any xdebug. So, I think it's disabled in this case.

Comment: also disable laravel-debugbar

Comment: Xampp is problem. When you upload your laravel package to server, it's very very fast!